# Makefile: Run other makefile from makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

So this is what I have:

```
SUBDIRS = src/lib/ResourceManager

all: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    make install -C $@
```

I am trying to execute the Makefile in `src/lib/ResourceManager`
when I run `make`

but it does not execute.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Recursive make commands should always use the variable `MAKE`, not the explicit command name ‘make’](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare SUBDIRS as a .PHONY target as the sub-directory obviously always exists; otherwise it won’t be built.

```
SUBDIRS = src/lib/ResourceManager
.PHONY: all $(SUBDIRS)
all: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    make install -C $@
```